# Unity IENumerator giving Unexpected symbol error and error 'cannot be an iterator block because 'void' is not an iterator interface type.'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ienumerator

I am trying to make a platform jumping game in Unity and when you die the game is supposed to show game over text and then wait 3 seconds. But I get these errors:

```
error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `(', expecting `,', `;', or `='
error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `IEnumerator'
```

**My Code** is:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

public float speed = 1700.0f;
public GameObject Player;
public Text TheText;

void Start()
{
    TheText.text = "";
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(movement * speed * Time.deltaTime);

    IEnumerator Wait1()
     { 
        if (Player.transform.position.y < -100.59)
        {
            TheText.text = "You Lost. Try Again!!";
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);

        }
    }
    IEnumerator Wait2()
    {
        if (Player.transform.position.y > 210)
        {
            TheText.text = "You Lost. Try Again!!";
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
        }
    }

 theres 4 more of those, they're all the same
```

I expect it to wait before restarting the game, but I get those errors. The `void fixedupdate();` statement gives the following error

```
cannot be an iterator block because 'void' is not an iterator interface type.
```

Comment: Perhaps point out which lines of code the errors relate to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to change your code like this: Basically close the FixedUpdate method and have IEnumerator Wait() as separate methods.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
 float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
 float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

 Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

 GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(movement * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}

IEnumerator Wait1()
{ 
    if (Player.transform.position.y < -100.59)
    {
        TheText.text = "You Lost. Try Again!!";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }
}
IEnumerator Wait2()
{
    if (Player.transform.position.y > 210)
    {
        TheText.text = "You Lost. Try Again!!";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use a feature of C#, introduced in version 7, called [local functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) in this code. Unfortunately Unity still uses C# v6 which means you need to move those functions outside of the `FixedUpdate` method. For example:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    //snip
}

IEnumerator Wait1()
{
    //snip
}

IEnumerator Wait2()
{
    //snip
}
```

Comment: Unity upgraded to Roselyn in Unity 2018.3 so you _can_ now use local functions if your Unity is up to date.

Comment: @Piflik Ah, nice to know thanks. I've never actually used Unity so this sort of info is helpful. +1 for your answer too.

Answer (score 1):

IEnumerators should be declared in class scope, not function scope, then triggered with StartCoroutine()

E.g.

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    // In this example we show how to invoke a coroutine and
    // continue executing the function in parallel.

    private IEnumerator coroutine;

    void Start()
    {
        // - After 0 seconds, prints "Starting 0.0"
        // - After 0 seconds, prints "Before WaitAndPrint Finishes 0.0"
        // - After 2 seconds, prints "WaitAndPrint 2.0"
        print("Starting " + Time.time);

        // Start function WaitAndPrint as a coroutine.

        coroutine = WaitAndPrint(2.0f);
        StartCoroutine(coroutine);

        print("Before WaitAndPrint Finishes " + Time.time);
    }

    // every 2 seconds perform the print()
    private IEnumerator WaitAndPrint(float waitTime)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
            print("WaitAndPrint " + Time.time);
        }
    }
}
```

Source: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html

Note the IEnumerator is defined in the class, not inside the Update() function.

You should also take care when you trigger your coroutines, as you can very easily trigger multiple coroutines at the same time, which wouldn't be ideal here (you could for instance, have 3 or 4 coroutines trying to load a level all at the same time, which would result in the level being loaded 3 or 4 times, causing a huge delay for the player along with potential unwanted sideeffects)

Asside: IEnumerators are not the same as Coroutines, Coroutines are a Unity feature allowing code to run in parallel (not threaded however) and they use IEnumerators (a C#) feature to work.

IEnumerators are a C# feature that has many capabilities beyond Coroutines, primarily it's used for iterating through custom containers (arrays, lists, etc)

Be careful with your terminology here as they're 2 very different (though related) things.

Answer (score 1):

Your code uses local functions, i.e. functions that are declared within another function. To use that feature, you must upgrade to Unity 2018.3 and make sure that your `Scripting Runtime Version` and `Api Compatibility Level` in `Player Settings` -> `Other Settings` are both set to .NET 4.x. Your code should work then.